How set font size on a lightning-button-menu?
How do I set the font size on a <lightning-button-menu> component.

I don't seem to be able to change it at all. I have tried styling hooks and regular css. No luck. Here is the code -
<div>
      <lightning-button-menu variant="bare" label={label.Actions}>
            <lightning-menu-item value="UpdateStage" label={label.Change_Stage}></lightning-menu-item>
            <lightning-menu-item value="Renew" label={label.Renew_Webstore}></lightning-menu-item>
            <lightning-menu-item value="ReqAdjustment" label={label.Request_Adjustment}></lightning-menu-item>
            <lightning-menu-item value="Purchase" label={label.Create_Purchase_Order}></lightning-menu-item>
            <lightning-menu-item value="NoRenew" label={label.Will_Not_Renew}></lightning-menu-item>
      </lightning-button-menu>
</div>

When I look at the browser CSS I see the following for the component -

When I changed the font to 1.1rem it did the trick. How do I access that font attribute?


How do I access that font attribute?

In general, you don't. The Shadow DOM specifically prevents unlimited access to the inside of a closed component:

CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child. In our example, a p style defined in the todoApp.css stylesheet doesn’t style the p element in the c-todo-item component, because the styles don’t reach into the shadow tree. See CSS.

The entire point of Style Hooks is to allow customization that otherwise wouldn't be possible (as it was in the beginning). The elements you can control here are the Style Hooks.
If you're developing for a Digital Experience, however, you can use the Settings > Advanced > Edit Header feature to add classes that override any standard SLDS class. If your component is inside Salesforce, however, you will be limited to just Style Hooks, which don't allow for changing the font size.

thanks for the confirmation. That's too bad.
